# Opencv Snake image

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I want to use the active contour OpenCV function. I have been trying different code but I cant figure out how to get the snake to run across the image. When I run the code below I receive the same points as the line I drew across the image. How can I check to see if the snake is actually running.

```
//USED TO OPEN IMAGE
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"

//USED TO GAUSSIAN FILTER

#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "opencv2/legacy/legacy.hpp"
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

void myLine(Mat copy, Point pt1, Point pt2);
void Extract(Mat copy, Point pt1, Point pt2);
void readFile(Mat copy);
void snake(Mat copy, CvPoint* pointsA);
//void ActiveSnake(Mat copy, Point pt1, Point pt2);

int main(){
    //CODE TO LOADING IMAGE
    Mat frame = imread ("First.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE); 

    //putText(frame,"First", Point (120, 330), 1, 4,  CV_RGB(255, 0, 0), 3, 8, false);

    int rows = frame.rows;
    int cols = frame.cols;
    //If the image wont appear
    if (frame.empty())
    {
        cout<<"No Image!"<<endl;
        return -1;
    } 

    //Cloning
    Mat copy = frame.clone();

    //Gaussian Filter (Originial Image, Clone Image, KSize(MUST BE POSITIVE OR ODD OR ZERO width,   height), sigmaX, sigmaY
    GaussianBlur(frame, copy, Size(9, 9), 0, 0);

    Point pt1, pt2;
    pt1.x = 0;
    pt1.y = 95;
    pt2.x = 900;
    pt2.y = 95;

    Extract (copy, pt1, pt2);

    readFile(copy);

    return 0;

}
void myLine (Mat copy, Point start, Point end)
{
    int thickness = 2;
    int lineType = 8;
    line (copy, start, end, Scalar(0,0,0), thickness, lineType);
}  

void Extract (Mat copy, Point pt1, Point pt2)
{ 
    myLine(copy, Point(pt1), Point (pt2));
    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open ("Test1.txt");
    int copypt1x;
    copypt1x = pt1.x;
    for (int i = pt1.x; i <=pt2.x; i++){
        for ( int j = pt1.y; 1 <=pt2.y; j++)
        {
            int copypt1y = pt1.y;
            myfile <<copypt1x<<"\t"<<copypt1y<<endl;
        }
        copypt1x= copypt1x +1;
        cout<<"\n";
    }
    myfile.close();
}

void readFile(Mat copy)
{
    ifstream myfile;
    CvPoint pointsA [1000];
    myfile.open("Test1.txt");

    if (!myfile.is_open()){
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    int i = 0;
    myfile >> pointsA[i].x>>pointsA[i].y;
    while (myfile.good()){
        i++;
        myfile >> pointsA[i].x>>pointsA[i].y;
    }

    snake(copy, pointsA);
}

void snake(Mat copy, CvPoint* pointsA)
{
    //IplImage* image2;
    //image2 = cvCloneImage(&(IplImage)copy);
    IplImage* image2;
    image2 = cvCreateImage(cvSize(copy.cols,copy.rows),8,3);
    IplImage ipltemp=copy;
    cvCopy(&ipltemp,image2);

    float alpha = 0.5; // Weight of continuity energy
    float beta = 0.5; // Weight of curvature energy
    float gamma = 0.9; // Weight of image energy

    CvSize size; // Size of neighborhood of every point used to search the minimumm have to be odd
    size.width = 5;
    size.height = 5;

    CvTermCriteria criteria;
    criteria.type = CV_TERMCRIT_ITER;  // terminate processing after X iteration
    criteria.max_iter = 10000; 
    criteria.epsilon = 0.1;

    int cpt = 1000;

    cvSnakeImage(image2, pointsA, cpt, &alpha, &beta, &gamma, CV_VALUE, size, criteria, 0);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "getting the snake to run across the image"? If I understand the cvSnakeImage function correctly, if it's given a single image, it will begin and then minimize the "energy" it has as a measure of contour area and pointy-ness. I don't think it's supposed to "run".

Comment: do **not** try to use cvSnakeImage. it was removed from opencv3, due to api as well as stability issues.

Comment: @MarkMiller I want to use CVSnakeImage to draw across the image above using the points from Test1.txt file.

Comment: @berak Do you have any suggestions besides cvSnake that will attempt the same thing.

Comment: The problem I am having is my program complies but the snake does not show. How do I get the cvsnake to show across the image.